# How do I draw touches (UIBezierPath) over a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibezierpath

Ok, I've spent hours searching and trying things and I'm coming up empty. Hopefully you all can help!

I need to draw with Apple Pencil (or finger, essentially) over a UICollectionView. Think circling cells, drawing arrows, that sort of thing. I'm using Apple's sample [CanvasView.swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TouchCanvas/Listings/TouchCanvas_CanvasView_swift.html) to subclass a UIView to draw on, and I've been able to set it as a subview of other views in order to draw on top of them with no problem. When I do this with UICollectionView, however, it doesn't work. If I put the View and CollectionView on the same "level" in the viewController and set the UICollectionView to hidden, it works. If the UICollectionView is visible, the lines are still drawn but are of course not visible through the UICollectionView. Any other way, nothing.

I've tried subclassing UICollectionViewController in order to come up with something myself, but can't seem to figure out how to make it work. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks!

Edit: adding more details below

This setup in IB (drawing over the PieChartView) works just fine:
[IB setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSck5.png)

The code I'm using is as follows (of course, with extraneous code cut out):

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - PROPERTIES

    @IBOutlet weak var pieCanvasView:  CanvasView!

    var canvasView: CanvasView!
    var visualizeAzimuth = false
    var table: Table!
    var masterView: MasterViewController!
    var updated: Bool! {
        didSet {
            if updated == true {
                // reload chart with new values when value changes
                updateDataSets(table.monthsToShow(), values: table.unitsSoldShow())
                pieChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - FUNCTIONS

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // lots of other chart-related stuff here
    }

    // MARK: - Chart

    func setChart(dataPoints:[String], values: [Double]) {
        // stuff for setting up the chart
    }

    func changeChartType(index: Int) {
    // stuff for changing the chart type
    }

    func updateDataSets(dataPoints:[String], values: [Double]) {
        // stuff for updating the chart
    }

    // MARK: - Touch Handling


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        canvasView.drawTouches(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        canvasView.drawTouches(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        canvasView.drawTouches(touches, withEvent: event)
        canvasView.endTouches(touches, cancel: false)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touches = touches else { return }
        canvasView.endTouches(touches, cancel: true)
    }

    override func touchesEstimatedPropertiesUpdated(touches: Set<NSObject>) {
        canvasView.updateEstimatedPropertiesForTouches(touches)
    }
}
```

So, in theory, this setup should work to draw on UICollectionView:

```
V View
  V CollectionView
      CanvasView
```

... but it doesn't. (Forgive the diagram, can't post more than 2 links yet)

I've tried subclassing UICollectionViewController as follows, with mixed results:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCanvas: UICollectionViewController {

    // MARK: - VARIABLES

    var visualizeAzimuth = false

    var table:      Table!
    var detailView: DetailViewController!
    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also set as cell identifier in storyboard
    var textView:     UITextView!
    var clearButton:  UIButton!
    var workingData: [Double]! = []

    var canvasView = CanvasView()

    // MARK: - FUNCTIONS

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.collectionView?.addSubview(canvasView)
        canvasView.hidden = false
     collectionView?.hidden = true
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

    // tell the collection view how many cells to make
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return self.items.count
        return self.table.COUNT
    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // cell formatting here
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // doing stuff in here that sets up the cells
        collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indices)
    }

    // MARK: - UICOllectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return -0.5
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cellWidth = collectionView.frame.width / 5.0
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 50)
    }

    // MARK: - Touches for CanvasView

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        canvasView.drawTouches(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        canvasView.drawTouches(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        canvasView.drawTouches(touches, withEvent: event)
        canvasView.endTouches(touches, cancel: false)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touches = touches else { return }
        canvasView.endTouches(touches, cancel: true)
    }

    override func touchesEstimatedPropertiesUpdated(touches: Set<NSObject>) {
        canvasView.updateEstimatedPropertiesForTouches(touches)
    }
}
```

In this case, with collectionView set to hidden, I'm able to trigger touchesBegan() with the Pencil. If collectionView is visible, touches go directly to didSelectItemAtIndexPath and that's that.

Hopefully that's helpful clarification!

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried and what works and what doesn't?

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox Updated. Please let me know if you'd like more info!